# Phpmyadmin on FreeBSD 10.3 and Nginx 1.10.1

Tags: nginx, freebsd, phpmyadmin

I am trying to install Phpmyadmin on a FreeBSD 10.3 server with Nginx 1.10.1 but it is not working. The Php version is 7.

It is a WPMU server, everything is working except Phpmyadmin which is giving me a 404.

Here is my Phpmyadmin block on Nginx

```
# PHPMYADMIN
location /phpmyadmin {
   root /usr/local/www/;
   index index.php index.html index.htm;
   location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
           try_files $uri =404;
           root /usr/local/www/;
           fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock; 
           # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
           fastcgi_index index.php;
           fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
           include /usr/local/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
   }
   location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
           root /usr/local/www/;
   }
}

location /phpMyAdmin {
   rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;
}
```

I have used this configuration on my Ubuntu server with no problem.

I also tried these tutorials with no success yet.

http://www.ostechnix.com/install-phpmyadmin-apache-nginx-freebsd-10-2/

I tried to copy config.inc.php.sample to config.inc.php following this

http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#manually-creating-the-file

How to make Phpmyadmin to work on FreeBSD/Nginx?

Answer (score 1):

I manage to access Phpmyadmin but I have to delete the rewrite part.

```
location /phpMyAdmin {
   rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;
}
```

And I have to go to http://my-domain.com/phpMyAdmin.

If I try http://my-domain.com/phpmyadmin would not work. I will try fix rewrite later.